# Optimizing qsort

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, optimization, qsort

I've been on a search for the fastest algorithm out there to sort 1,000,000 integers. So far, surprisingly, C's built in qsort function seems to be the fastest out of anything that I've tried (I've tested pre sorted, reverse sorted, and random input files). On average, I get about .07 seconds for pre and reverse sorted and .2 seconds for random.

How can I optimize it to run even faster? Are there any quick tricks? I know that C++'s std sort is faster, but that can't be used in C... I've attached my code.

```
int compare(const void *x, const void *y){   
   return ( *(int*)x >= *(int*)y );
}

qsort(list, 1000000, sizeof(int), compare);
```

Comment: What do you know about the integers you're trying to sort?

Comment: You should start over and make sure the results you're getting are actually sorted. Your compare function is not valid as written so you're probably getting nonsense.

Comment: You don't know that your particular C++ implementation's `std::sort()` is faster than your particular C implementation's `qsort()` for your particular problems until and unless you test the two.

Comment: @R What is wrong with compare? Looks ok to me.. Upd: Ah, I think I see. Should it return the difference instead of boolean?

Comment: The `qsort` algorithm is already pretty fast in general. It's reasonable to assume a widely used library implementation already has been optimized as much as possible.

Comment: If you fix your `compare` function, it's going to be hard to beat `qsort`. If the integers fall into a predictable range, you might be able to use an O(n) sort, which will be faster. (I'm partial to merge sort myself - it's stable and predictable.)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: `qsort` expects a comparison function that returns _[negative,zero,positive]_ values to determine ordering.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Right, figured it out already..

Comment: If your integers fall in a reasonably narrow range, then a histogram sort is hard to beat.  If they fall in a wide(r) range but have roughly uniform distribution, then a flashsort will probably beat qsort.  Histogram sort is O(n), and flashsort is O(n) provided reasonably uniform distribution, whereas quicksort is O(n log n) in the best and typical cases.

Comment: Candidate fix: `return ( *(int*)x > *(int*)y )  -  ( *(int*)x < *(int*)y );`

Comment: I don't know why so many people are surprised when standard library functions turn out to be fast. The standard libraries are typically written by professional programmers with a lot of experience in optimization who have studied algorithms and understand the characteristics of the compilers. It's not like they're out to produce a bad product.

Comment: @rici: I think you're right about some functions like `qsort`, but in other domains, like LAPACK, sometimes they've optimized for generality rather than ultimate speed.

Comment: Could always try [Quantum Bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort#Related_algorithms) which is `O(n)`.  ;-)

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: Certainly there are even faster implementations of LAPACK, but I wouldn't even pretend to be able to do so well myself. (Certainly portability is paramount, which can produce some platform-specific optimization opportunities.) qsort, on the other hand, does suffer from the generality issues which is why a C++ standard library sort is probably a lot faster for simple objects: qsort requires a function call for every compare, which C++ can usually inline. So a good programming student could probably succeed in beating qsort for a specific value domain.

Comment: @rici: [*Here's*](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262) an example of what I mean about LAPACK. For multiplying large matrices a small number of times, it's great. But if you're multiplying small matrices a large number of times, what I found is it can easily spend 50-90% of its time just calling LSAME to classify its arguments. So there, if you just write your own routines you win big.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: It's true, the netlib BLAS `LSAME` implementation seems ridiculous these days, but I'd say it's a portability issue, not a generality issue. (Perhaps that's too much semantics.) Out of curiosity, did you check the difference between using  `'N'` and `'n'` as the character parameter? -- Although that won't help you with `'T'`.

Comment: @rici: It's been a few years. In our product I had to do a lot of performance tuning. That's just one point that sticks in my mind. We did many things to make sure we were as fast as, or faster than, our competition.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: I think we've all done that at some time or another. But I never expect it to be easy.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Returning the difference can fail if the values being compared are far apart; for example, `INT_MAX - INT_MIN` won't give you a positive result (in fact it's undefined behavior). One trick I've seen is `((*(int*)y > *(int*)x)) - ((*(int*)x > *(int*)y))`

Comment: The reason for C++ 's std::sort() function being faster is probably inlining. When profiling programs using qsort() in std C, the compare() function will show up , even above qsort() itself. function calls are expensive if they cannot be inlined (register trashing, pipeline drains). If sorting is **really** the bottleneck: roll your own, at least in C. For smaller sizes: insertion or selection sort, or merge sort. For larger sizes: merge sort in common cases). For low cardinality: some counting or radix variant. IMHO

Comment: The reason I'm not returning the subtraction is because if the two numbers happen to be really large negative numbers, it will overflow. The compare function I wrote is sorting them correctly. I wrote a for loop to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This counting / radix sort will sort 1,000,000 32 bit unsigned integers in about .01 seconds on my system (Intel 2600K 3.4ghz), but it uses a second array (pTemp) the same size as the original array (pData), so it needs twice the memory.

```
typedef unsigned int UI32;

UI32 * RadixSort(UI32 * pData, UI32 * pTemp, size_t count)
{
size_t mIndex[4][256] = {0};            // index matrix
UI32 *pDst, *pSrc, *pTmp;
size_t i,j,m,n;
UI32 u;

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){         // generate histograms
        u = pData[i];
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            mIndex[j][(size_t)(u & 0xff)]++;
            u >>= 8;
        }       
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){             // convert to indices
        n = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
            m = mIndex[j][i];
            mIndex[j][i] = n;
            n += m;
        }       
    }
    pDst = pTemp;                       // radix sort
    pSrc = pData;
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
            u = pSrc[i];
            m = (size_t)(u >> (j<<3)) & 0xff;
            pDst[mIndex[j][m]++] = u;
        }
        pTmp = pSrc;
        pSrc = pDst;
        pDst = pTmp;
    }
    return(pSrc);
}
```

For signed integers, just need to complement the sign bit of an integer when it's used for indexing:

```
typedef          int  I32;
typedef unsigned int UI32;

I32 * RadixSort(I32 * pData, I32 * pTemp, size_t count)
{
size_t mIndex[4][256] = {0};            // index matrix
UI32 *pDst, *pSrc, *pTmp;
size_t i,j,m,n;
UI32 u;

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){         // generate histograms
        u = pData[i];
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if(j != 3)                  //  signed integer handling
                mIndex[j][(size_t)(u & 0xff)]++;
            else
                mIndex[j][(size_t)((u^0x80) & 0xff)]++;
            u >>= 8;
        }       
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){             // convert to indices
        n = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
            m = mIndex[j][i];
            mIndex[j][i] = n;
            n += m;
        }       
    }
    pDst = (UI32 *)pTemp;               // radix sort
    pSrc = (UI32 *)pData;
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
            u = pSrc[i];
            if(j != 3)                  //  signed integer handling
                m = (size_t)(u >> (j<<3)) & 0xff;
            else
                m = (size_t)((u >> (j<<3))^0x80) & 0xff;
            pDst[mIndex[j][m]++] = u;
        }
        pTmp = pSrc;
        pSrc = pDst;
        pDst = pTmp;
    }
    return((I32 *)pSrc);
}
```

Comment: Can this same function work with regular ints? @rcgldr

Comment: @Mitch - if you mean signed integers, the easiest way to do this would be to complement the sign bit of every integer in the array (^= 0x80000000), before and after the sort. Or unfold the loops and used signed characters for the 4th loop in each of the loops in the code, or check for j == 3 and use signed character for the loops. These last two suggestions assume a right shift of a signed integer will copy the sign bit.

Comment: Even when using only positive ints, the output of the program doesn't seem to actually sort the numbers for some reason. @rcgldr

Comment: @Mitch - I've tested this against other sort programs and the output is OK for me. Do you have example code that generates the data and calls the sort function? You are sorting 32 bit signed integers and not 64 bit integers? I assume the data is stored in memory in little endian format if using an X86 type processor?

Comment: Here is my full c file. It makes a random input file, converts that to an array, and then calls the sorting algorithm with it and times it. I have my previous qsort in there as well as a comb sort that I was testing out too https://www.sendspace.com/file/vh8618

Comment: In sorting.c, instead of allocating space for a second array, you just assign the address of the primary array to a second pointer. You need to allocate space for a second array :  |  int * list2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000000); |  (don't forget to free list2 after the radix sort returns).

Comment: Ah duh, stupid me... As for complementing the sign bits, wouldn't that add a lot more time by going through the entire array 2 extra times? @rcgldr

Comment: @Baller103 - I added a second example code that handles 32 bit signed integers.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble making sense of your bitwise operations and therefore, how the algorithm is actually working. I'm very interested in learning this topic, so can you maybe explain each part? I'm just trying to understand as much as I possibly can

Comment: Wiki link: [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). This is the simple case where integers are being sorted, but I did not combine the 2nd and 3rd loops as suggested in the wiki article.